# Linear Regression in R - Constraints & Varying Number of Regressors

Tags: r, constraints, linear-regression

I want to do a linear regression with a varying number of regressors (sometimes 3, sometimes 15) and specific inequality constraints to some of the regressor coefficients: some shall be >= 0, others can also be negative.

I have done this with `optim()` and `constrOptim()` which both refer to another user-defined function that minimizes the residuals of the regression. My problem is that this will only give me coefficients and no additional data like residuals, $R^2$, etc.

Is there an easy way to use `lm()`, `nl()` or any other function that would account for the inequality constraints while being able to handle a varying number of regressors?

Comment: may be pcls in the  [mgcv package](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Fmgcv%2Fmgcv.pdf) will help. It seem to perform some Penalized weighted least squares with linear equality and inequality constraints.

Answer (score 0):

As a linear regression is somehow an orthogonal projection onto a vectorial space, it is not meaningfull to talk about linear regression with constrained coefficient.

In any case, once a model is fitted all the statistical quantities can always be calculated via the direct formula : if your output is `y`and your model predicts `y_pred` then `R^2 = mean((y-y_pred)^2)` etc.

Beware that confidence on the regression is not accurate anymore since it is based on some assumptions on the error term (iid normaly distributed)